# How to get pandas DataFrame from a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dictionary:

```
{
  'aaa': 
   {
     'x1': 879,
     'x2': 861,
     'x3': 876,
     'x4': 873
   },
 'bbb': 
   {
     'y1': 700,
     'y2': 801,
     'y3': 900
   }
}`
```

I need to transform it into the pandas DataFrame:

```
col1 col2  col3
aaa  x1    879
aaa  x2    861
aaa  x3    876
aaa  x4    873
bbb  y1    700
bbb  y2    801
bbb  y3    900
```

If I use `from_dict` function, then the output is different.

How can I get the DataFrame as shown above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Try `stack`:

```
d = {
  'aaa': 
   {
     'x1': 879,
     'x2': 861,
     'x3': 876,
     'x4': 873
   },
 'bbb': 
   {
     'y1': 700,
     'y2': 801,
     'y3': 900
   }
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.stack()
```

Output:

```
x1  aaa    879.0
x2  aaa    861.0
x3  aaa    876.0
x4  aaa    873.0
y1  bbb    700.0
y2  bbb    801.0
y3  bbb    900.0
dtype: float64
```

OR to get exact output:

```
df.stack().reset_index().set_axis(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2   col3
0   x1  aaa  879.0
1   x2  aaa  861.0
2   x3  aaa  876.0
3   x4  aaa  873.0
4   y1  bbb  700.0
5   y2  bbb  801.0
6   y3  bbb  900.0
```

#### Or use `melt`:

```
df.reset_index().melt('index').dropna()
```

Output:

```
   index variable  value
0     x1      aaa  879.0
1     x2      aaa  861.0
2     x3      aaa  876.0
3     x4      aaa  873.0
11    y1      bbb  700.0
12    y2      bbb  801.0
13    y3      bbb  900.0
```

To get proper column naming:

```
df.rename_axis(['col1']).reset_index().melt('col1', var_name='col2',value_name='col3').dropna()
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2   col3
0    x1  aaa  879.0
1    x2  aaa  861.0
2    x3  aaa  876.0
3    x4  aaa  873.0
11   y1  bbb  700.0
12   y2  bbb  801.0
13   y3  bbb  900.0
```

Comment: I get Series instead of DataFrame.

Comment: You can reset_index() after stack() to get dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').stack().reset_index().rename(
        columns={'level_0': 'col1', 'level_1': 'col2', 0: 'col3'})
df.col3 = df.col3.astype(int)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  col3
0  aaa   x1   879
1  aaa   x2   861
2  aaa   x3   876
3  aaa   x4   873
4  bbb   y1   700
5  bbb   y2   801
6  bbb   y3   900
```

Comment: I get Series instead of DataFrame.

Comment: Are you passing the dictionary in as ``data`` and running the exact code above?